# Insufficient memory available for raster calculator on DEM with float 32 pixel type

Tags: qgis, raster-calculator

I merged 102 Tiff files downloaded from ASTER: https://earthexplorer.usgs.gov/.

They were each 17 MB, plus or minus. I merged them using the Processing toolbox/GDAL merge tool. I am trying to use the raster calculator on it, but I get an error message saying `Insufficient memory available for the operation`. The pixel type is float 32, and I heard at my [previous question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/277870/merging-rasters-using-qgis-raster-calculator/277902?noredirect=1#comment443265_277902) that this may be making the file size too big.

About my computer:
7.8 GiB of memory
32 bit
483.8 GB disk space (128.5 used)
Ubuntu 16.04 LTS
QGIS 2.18.11

I have tried changing the pixel type with GDAL Translate, but I get an error message saying no output file was created: [image]

When I use `r.mapcalc` to do the raster calculation, I click run and it seems to work, but no file is saved and no layer appears. I tried using both the name of the file in the Layers panel and its filename.

[image]
[image]

I could try merging the different rasters into small groups, but idoes anyone know an easier way?

Comment: What's your calc? It doesn't seem right that you're out of memory, GDAL is usually pretty good at that.. your disc space: is that system drive as well? Would you consider doing the calc in python?

Comment: The ASTGMT2 source dem files are 16 bit signed interger

Answer (score 5):

Well, judging by the first screenshot you provided, seems to me that you are **not specifying the output file to produce** to the translate, which you should:

[image]

This is probably the reason why you get the "no output file created" warning.

Besides that, I don't see why you could be running out of memory from a rastercalc. Seems that 102*17MB is 1734MB, or about 1.7GB. Personally, I have run raster calculations (NDVI, etc.) on Tiff files of about 3GB without problems at all; sure it's takes some time but it outputs the calculation.

Some other things you could check are:

- Make sure the output folder for your calculation has write permissions.
- Check if that disk space is *really* what you have available, perhaps your partition or similar has less space available.
- You can also try doing what suggested [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/185947/raster-calculator-insufficient-memory-available-for-operation), and use `r.mapcalculator` or well [`gdal_calc`](http://www.gdal.org/gdal_calc.html)

Alternatively, you can consider loading your Tiff on Python and doing the calculation on your bands there. The way I do it is to open the file with OpenCV (or with imread for large images) and then operate it with a Numpy array, something like:

```py
from skimage.io import imread
import numpy as np
#read image
img = imread("yourImage.tif")
#load as float 32 Numpy array
img = np.float32(img)

#then do your calculations, for example NDVI:
#(B1-B3)/(B1+B3)
#Using Python's slicing, operate on all pixels by bands
ndvi = (img[:,:,0] - img[:,:,2]) / (img[:,:,0] + img[:,:,2])
```

You can then use your calculation `ndvi` as you wish.

Comment: I was able to convert to Int16 thanks to you, but the raster calculator still said there was not enough available memory. I'll try the other options.

Comment: Ok, surely python wont fail. As a side note, remember that numpy loads into memory (RAM) so if your array is N kb it will take N kb from memory